# Calculate the mean of signal \$ e^{-j2\pi t^2} \$

Tags: signal, telecommunications

I'm a trying to calculate the mean value of the signal \$ e^{-j2\pi t^2} \$

Here is my attempt:
$$ <x\left(t\right)>\triangleq\lim_{T \to \infty}{\frac{1}{2T}\int_{-T}^{T}x\left(t\right)dt}=\lim_{T \to \infty}{\frac{1}{2T}\int_{-T}^{T}{e^{-j2\pi t^2}dt}}=\lim_{T \to \infty}{\frac{1}{2T}\int_{-T}^{T}{\cos{\left(-2\pi t^2\right)}+j\sin{(-2\pi t^2)}dt}}=\lim_{T \to \infty}{\frac{1}{2T}\int_{-T}^{T}{\cos{\left(2\pi t^2\right)}-j\sin{(2\pi t^2)}dt}}=\lim_{T \to \infty}{\frac{1}{2T}\int_{-T}^{T}{\cos{\left(2\pi t^2\right)}dt}-j\int_{-T}^{T}{\sin{(2\pi t^2)}dt}}=\lim_{T \to \infty}{\frac{1}{2T}\int_{-T}^{T}{\cos{\left(2\pi t^2\right)}dt}} $$

However, when I reach that part, doesn't matter if I try to solve the integral by substitution or by parts, I can't get a proper result without using the \$ \text{erf}(z) \$ function.

Am I doing something wrong or there is a "trick" which I don't know about it?

Also, I calculated the mean with Wolfram, so I know the result is 0 ([source](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=lim%20T-%3Einfinity%20%281%2F%282T%29%20*%20%28integral%20from%20-T%20to%20T%20%28e%5E%28-i*2*pi*x%5E2%29%29%29%29)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How did you make the sine term disappear when you were unable to solve for the cosine term? It should be something very similar that solves both terms.

Those integrals do not actually converge for \$T\rightarrow\infty\$ so you can't actually obtain a numerical result. But that's a red herring. You don't need that to obtain an answer.

All you need is to show that the integral of sine and cosine are always a finite number regardless of the argument. If you can show that the integral of sine and cosine are always bounded between two finite numbers, then that is enough because they will be overwhelmed if you divide them by the limit of 2T. You could prove that for any symmetrical integration interval since that is the specific case you are interested or you could prove that for any interval; It doesn't matter.

You don't even need to solve the integral as written. It should be enough to show that the integral of cos(u) and sin(u) will always be between two finite values for any value of u.

So the solution is not so much about solving the integral as much as it is looking at what is actually going on, which is really easy trap to fall into if you're a student but that's not what mathematicians actually do! To come up with new math and solve weird problems then can't just manipulate what's on the page. They have to look at and think about what is going on and sometimes even hypothesize and answer they think it should be and try to prove for that. For instance, in your case you know the answer is zero and you could probably guess that from looking at your equation).

Comment: I assumed the \$ \sin(t^2) \$ was an odd function, my bad! Also, thanks, with your answer and using https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_integral#Limits_as_x_approaches_infinity with the propierty of even functions (the integral of an even function from −A to +A is twice the integral from 0 to +A) I solved the problem :)

Answer (score 1):

\$T\$ symbolizes the period of \$x(t)\$. When you consider some particular periodic function, you need to use its specific period. One period of the exponential is, for example, the interval from 0 to 1, or from 1 to \$\sqrt{2}\$, or from \$\sqrt{2}\$ to \$\sqrt{3}\$, and so on. So integrate across one of these specific periods, rather than two of them, and divide by \$T\$ rather than \$2T\$. Then use the substitution \$u=t^2\$, \$du=2 dt\$. Both integrals can then easily be seen to evaluate to 0.